# MYSQL case when in statement not working

Tags: mysql

MYSQL:

```
SELECT    `item`.*, 
          CASE( 
             WHEN `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN('65', '66','67', '68') 
             AND       `item_category`.`category` IN('35', '36') 
             THEN 0 ELSE 1
          ) AS condition 
FROM      `items` 
LEFT JOIN `item_category` 
    ON        `item_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `item_sub_category` 
    ON        `item_sub_category`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `cart` 
    ON        `cart`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
    AND       `cart`.`USER` = 3 
LEFT JOIN `user_users` 
    ON        `user_users`.`id` = 3 
WHERE     `cart`.`item` IS NULL 
    AND       `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN('65','66', '67', '68') 
    OR        `item_category`.`category` IN('35', '36') 
GROUP BY  `item`.`id` 
ORDER BY  `item`.`id` DESC, `item`.`feature` DESC 
limit 4
```

Anyone can please tell me why ut displaying syntax error and How can I resolve the syntax error? Maybe syntax error is on below given Line.

```
  CASE( 
     WHEN `item_sub_category`.`sub_category` IN('65', '66','67', '68') 
     AND       `item_category`.`category` IN('35', '36') 
     THEN 0 ELSE 1
  ) AS condition
```

Comment: Your `CASE` expression is missing an `END`: `... THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS condition`

Comment: Still, the error continues.

Comment: This means there is an additional error in your code. Can you post the actual error message that you get?

Answer (score 2):

Put it like:

```
CASE 
     WHEN item_sub_category.sub_category IN(65, 66,67, 68) 
     AND  item_category.category IN(35, 36) 
     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
   AS condition
```

i.e. put and **END** and **do NOT use brackets**. Brackets, if used, should encapsulate the entire `case` statement, not from `when`.
Also, you may avoid single quotes if the numbers are integers.